# How to assign a specific color scale to all specific objects in the scene

Tags: python, scripting

I have some meshes in the scene (7 mesh objects for example). I want to assign each object a color. The color should vary in a specific scale. For example: green scale. So, first object has green value 0.1, second 0.2 and so on. So in the end, I can able to see a pattern of color.

All this I want as a BoolProperty checkbox button in my UI Panel. So, when I check it, it should show me colors and vice versa.

```
def switch(self, context):
   bool = context.scene.bool
   objects = bpy.data.objects
   mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
   if bool == True:
       print ("True")
       for ind, object in enumerate(bpy.context.scene.objects):
           mat = bpy.data.materials.new("BSDF")
           val = 0.0
           mat.diffuse_color = (float(val), 1, float(val))
           object[ind].active_material = mat 
           val += .1

    else:
        for ind, object in enumerate(bpy.context.scene.objects):
            object[ind].active_material.delete()
```

This is what I want to achieve but it's not working.

Comment: `Object.active_material.delete()` ?

Comment: I don't know, whether it is correct or wrong. I just want to give an idea of what I want to do. Basically, I want a switch check box that will turn on off the color of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to iterate thru mesh (or meta i suppose) objects that can have a material.  Here is a sample, changing `scene.bool` removes material if False, or adds a new material to each object with a differing shade of green.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

def toggle_bool(self, context):

    val = 0.0
    for o in self.objects:
        if o.type not in {'MESH', 'META'}:
            continue

        if self.bool:
            print(o, val)
            mat = bpy.data.materials.new("BSDF")
            mat.diffuse_color = (val, 1, val)

            o.active_material = mat
            val += 0.1
        else:
            o.active_material = None

bpy.types.Scene.bool = BoolProperty(update=toggle_bool)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use another toggle_bool function to inverse the coloring scheme. I mean something like this: {o_1 : 0, o_2 : 0.1, o_3 : 0.3} can be converted to {o_3: 0, o_2 : 0.2, o_1 : 0.3}. Can you briefly comment as well to make it easier to understand.